# Group by without temporary table and filesort

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate

My aim is to make the following query faster.

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE Links.id,Links.link,sum(ID_Links_Words.count) AS wordCount 
 FROM Links LEFT JOIN ID_Links_Words ON Links.id = ID_Links_Words.link 
 WHERE ID_Links_Words.word IN ('1025','1056','2353') GROUP BY Links.id
```

My table Links has the columns

`id,link,title,description and timestamp`

and the keys `id (Primary),link (index), timestamp (index), (link,title,description) (fulltext)`

The table ID_Links_Words has the columns

`link, word, count`

and the keys `(link,word) (UNIQUE), link (index), word (index)`

```
 |id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys     | key | key_len | ref                | rows | Extra 
 |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | 1     SIMPLE     ID_Links_Words   range link,link_2,word    word     4       NULL                 6        Using where; Using  temporary; Using filesort|
 |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | 1     SIMPLE     Links           eq_ref   PRIMARY           PRIMARY   4     ID_Links_Words.link   1
 |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Sorry for this bad explain table :/ Hope you can read it.
I would like to get rid of the `using temporary` and I'm not sure if it's possible. Are there any options to improve this sql statement? I might have to deal with about 100,000 words and 1,000 links.

Answer (score 1):

Is ID_Links_Words a many-to-many table for connecting `Words` and `Links`?  Then this is the optimal schema:

```
CREATE TABLE ID_Links_Words(
    word ... NOT NULL,
    link ... NOT NULL,
    count ... NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(word, link), -- for going one direction
    INDEX(link, word)        -- and the other
) ENGINE = InnoDB;           -- Important because of the clustering of the PK.
```

The two indexes can be swapped, depending on the various queries you do; this arrangement -- with `word` first in the PRIMARY KEY -- is best for *this* SELECT.

Remove `LEFT` unless there is a compelling reason for it.

What percentage of the table has those 3 'words'?  If it is a non-trivial percentage, you are stuck with a table scan.

Check the settings of innodb_buffer_pool_size and key_buffer_size.

What version of MySQL are you using?  There were improvements in the handling of IN(...) in 5.6, perhaps before.  If you are in an older version, recommend upgrading.

If the my other hints don't do enough, try this:

```
(   SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE L.id, L.link, sum(W.count) AS wordCount
        FROM  Links AS L
        LEFT JOIN  ID_Links_Words AS W ON L.id = W.link
        WHERE  W.word = '1025'
        GROUP BY  W.link 
)
UNION  ALL (
    SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE L.id, L.link, sum(W.count) AS wordCount
        FROM  Links AS L
        LEFT JOIN  ID_Links_Words AS W ON L.id = W.link
        WHERE  W.word = '1056'
        GROUP BY  W.link 
           )
UNION  ALL (
    SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE L.id, L.link, sum(W.count) AS wordCount
        FROM  Links AS L
        LEFT JOIN  ID_Links_Words AS W ON L.id = W.link
        WHERE  W.word = '2353'
        GROUP BY  W.link
           );
```

And, assuming that the `LEFT` is not necessary, test this

SELECT  W.link as id, 
        ( SELECT  link
            FROM  Links
            WHERE  id = W.link 
        ) AS link,
        wordCount
    FROM
      ( SELECT  SUM(count) AS wordCount
            FROM  ID_Links_Words
            WHERE  word IN ('1025','1056','2353')
            GROUP BY  link 
      ) AS W ;

This, if I wrote it right, has the following potential benefits:

- The GROUP BY is done without being bothered by the other table.
- The other table is done *after* shrinking the number of rows by the GROUP BY.

Again, the IN could be turned into a UNION.

**Edit**

There is a world of difference between `INDEX(word, link)` and `INDEX(link, word)`.  INDEXes are ordered.  If you have a `word` and need to find the `links` associated with it, the former is much better.  If you have a `link` and want to find the `words` the latter is much better.  Imagine looking in a list of names ordered by (last_name, first_name), and looking for all the last names, given a first name.

[Index cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: thanks for your response. Can you quickly explain why there is a difference between the index `(link,word)` and `(word,link)` ? And why the last one is better for this query?